# Alcohol and cannabis

Tags: specialty-beers

Constellation Brands (STZ) has agreed to pay $190 million for a 10% stake in Canopy Growth Corporation, which sells medical marijuana in Canada and plans to sell recreational pot there when it becomes legal, as soon as next July. Who will be the next Alcoholic beverage company to strike a deal with a cannabis based company?

Comment: This is too broad and unanswerable. I vote to close

Comment: Is this a FUTURE PREDICTIONS SITE?  How can you have a future predictions market if no one predicts the future? Any knid of future prediction is opinion based.

Comment: @watermark No, this is not a "future predictions site". This is a "question and answer site for alcoholic beverage aficionados and those interested in beer, wine, or spirits."

Comment: Augur Stack Exchange
https://augur.stackexchange.com/

Q&A for developers, economists and users interested in the open source, decentralized, prediction market, Augur.              ( I copied this from Google. Why does its read " prediction market"

Comment: @watermark This is not Augur Stack Exchange. This is Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange [alcohol.stackexchange.com](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com). They are both different subsites of the Stack Exchange network. [There are many such subsites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?#users), which all specialize in different topics.